# What does this ANLTR4 notation mean?

Tags: grammar, antlr4, ucb-logo

I have a question regarding the notation of a UCB Logo grammar that I found was generated for ANTLR4. There are some notations can't make out and thought about asking. If anyone is willing to clarify, I will be grateful.
Here are the notations I don't quite understand:

```
WORD
: {listDepth > 0}?  ~[ \t\r\n\[\];] ( ~[ \t\r\n\];~] | LINE_CONTINUATION | '\\' ( [ \t\[\]();~] | LINE_BREAK ) )*
| {arrayDepth > 0}? ~[ \t\r\n{};]   ( ~[ \t\r\n};~]  | LINE_CONTINUATION | '\\' ( [ \t{}();~]   | LINE_BREAK ) )*;

array
: '{' ( ~( '{' | '}' ) | array )* '}';

NAME
: ~[-+*/=<> \t\r\n\[\]()":{}] ( ~[-+*/=<> \t\r\n\[\](){}] | LINE_CONTINUATION | '\\' [-+*/=<> \t\r\n\[\]();~{}] )*;
```

I guess the array means that it can start with { and have an arbitrary number of levels, but has to end with }.
I take it that the others are some form of regular expressions? 
Too my knowledge, regex is different for different programming languages.

Did I get that right?

Answer (score 1):

Antlr does not do regular expressions. It does implement some of the same operators, but that is where the similarity largely ends.

The first sub-terms ( `{listDepth > 0}?`) in the `WORD` rule are predicates - no relation to anything in the regular expression world. They are defined in the Antlr documentation and explained in detail in the TDAR.

Your understanding of the `array` rule is essentially correct.